# Correct sentence for "to motivate" usage

Tags: translation

I am writing a summary for the project I have completed. For this I need the translation of the sentence: "A system for children to motivate them to make sports". For this which of the following translations is correct?

```
Ein System für die Kinder, für Sport zu motivieren
```

or

```
Ein System für die Kinder, um Sport zu motivieren
```

or

```
Ein System für die Kinder, für sie um Sport zu motivieren
```

Comment: Are the children an active part of the system/will they motivate each other?

Comment: @Grantwalzer. It is an electronic system (a hardware) which will communicate with children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Ein System, um Kinder zum Sport zu motivieren".